# Python Matplotlib: black squares when saving eps of plot of masked array, why?

Tags: python, matplotlib, eps

When I run the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_data = np.random.randn(10000)
y_data = np.random.randn(10000)
hist, xbins, ybins = np.histogram2d(x_data, y_data, bins=100)
hist_masked = np.ma.masked_where(hist<1e-3, hist)

cmap = matplotlib.cm.jet
#cmap.set_bad('w',1.)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.imshow(hist_masked.T, interpolation = 'none', cmap = cmap)
plt.savefig('test.eps',transparent=False)
plt.show()
```

the plot looks fine on screen but the eps file has extra black "squares". Why?
These black squares are present only if I save the plot as eps and even with eps I can get rid of them by uncommenting the "set_bad" command in the code. Why is that command necessary for the plot to work if I am plotting a masked array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The masked array `hist_masked` sets the *bad* values to `np.nan` and the colormaps in matplotlib have a predefined value for nans:

```
In [5]: plt.cm.jet._rgba_bad
Out[5]: (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

So it is set to black and fully transparent by default. However, when you set `transparent=False` upon saving, these points actually become visible (since the alpha is set to 1).

When you use:

```
cmap.set_bad('w',1.)
```

you set the *bad* color to white (`'w'`), and therefore you will not see them in the resulting eps file.

eps files can't handle transparency. However, you could consider saving to `pdf` and removing the flag `transparency=False`. This would also solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks, for the reply. I didn't realize that the values the mask covered were treated as nans. I am still confused though as to why it is not the whole area of the plot that becomes black but only some "pixels" near the edges and near some individual points. Shouldn't the whole area be masked and therefore be black?

Comment: Good point, you're right. Actually after closer inspection of the eps that I get, it seems that each non-zero pixel has a black neighbor to the left and below.